# How to disable a input in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, disabled-input

In ts `is_edit = true` to disable...

```
<input [disabled]="is_edit=='false' ? true : null" id="name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.name" formControlName="name" class="form-control" minlength="2">
```

I just simply want to disable a input based on `true` or `false`.

I tried following:

```
[disabled]="is_edit=='false' ? true : null"
[disabled]="is_edit=='true'"
[disabled]="is_edit"
```

Comment: You already asked this question, and already had an answer, but then deleted the question. Again, open your browser console to notice the errors, fix them (i.e. use name and not formControlName), and then, it works: http://plnkr.co/edit/al2IkGkaZKpdLKKTfvKh?p=preview

Comment: The real problem here is that you're mixing template-based forms with reactive forms. Use one or the other, not both. @AJT_82 has the correct answer.

Answer (score 412, accepted):

Try using `attr.disabled`, instead of `disabled`

```html
<input [attr.disabled]="disabled ? '' : null"/>
```

Comment: Setting attr value to null in order to NOT add the attr to element - looks like a hack - but it actually works, and even makes sence, in a hindsight.

Comment: `disabled` equals to `true` or `false`

Comment: Thank you for an answer that actually works! So why does `attr.disabled` work when `disabled` does not?

Comment: Why angular document didn't say anything about this?

Comment: While this works, it's a hack that doesn't address the real problem of mixing template-based forms with reactive forms. The OP should be using one or the other, not both.

Comment: <input [attr.disabled]="disabled || null"/>   I think work also

Comment: This does not work in more recent versions of Angular. You can use `[disabled]="disabled"`.

Comment: Importante note: [attr.disabled]=false won't work, it has to be null. Don't ask me why

Comment: this is not a good approach, because the user can delete this attribute via the browser, in which case it will change in the data in the model?

Comment: The currently recommended approach when using reactive forms (to avoid 'changed after checked' errors) is to set up a disabled property in your component class and the disabled attribute will be set in the DOM for you, more at https://stackoverflow.com/a/64291577/4742336

Answer (score 56):

If you want input to disable on some statement.
use `[readonly]=true` or `false` instead of disabled.

```
<input [readonly]="this.isEditable" 
    type="text" 
    formControlName="reporteeName" 
    class="form-control" 
    placeholder="Enter Name" required>
```

Comment: Reactive-friendly solution.

Comment: This is correct. For me [attr.disabled]="disabled" worked one-way only i.e. input stayed in initial disabled/enabled state

Comment: The currently recommended approach when using reactive forms (to avoid 'changed after checked' errors) is to set up a disabled property in your component class and the disabled attribute will be set in the DOM for you, more at https://stackoverflow.com/a/64291577/4742336

Answer (score 46):

I think I figured out the problem, this input field is part of a reactive form (?), since you have included `formControlName`. This means that what you are trying to do by disabling the input field with `is_edit` is not working, e.g your attempt `[disabled]="is_edit"`, which would in other cases work. With your form you need to do something like this:

```
toggle() {
  let control = this.myForm.get('name')
  control.disabled ? control.enable() : control.disable();
}
```

and lose the `is_edit` altogether.

if you want the input field to be disabled as default, you need to set the form control as:

```
name: [{value: '', disabled:true}]
```

Here's a **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5qC3mjRytyeonRZcBoZ8)**

Comment: Disabling an input means disabling its validations as well. This one is the only answer that achieves this goal and properly disable the input. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 37):

You could simply do this

```
<input [disabled]="true" id="name" type="text">
```

Comment: While this works, it suggests that "false" would enable the control, which it doesn´t since the presence of the disabled attribute is what diabled the control, not the value.

Comment: @Mecaveli, setting [disabled] to false actually enables the control.

  <input [disabled]="false" id="name" type="text">
makes the input field enabled. You could check over your angular application.

Comment: Just to correct myself here: As i learned, [disabled] doesn´t actually control the "disabled" html attribute value like [attr.disabled] would. Therefor, [disabled]="false" works although "false" as value for the html attribute "disable" would not.

Comment: So in all, you should actually use your editor and try it out before bringing up a counter point.

Comment: Indeed, sorry for downvoting unfortunately can´t undo it now. Was misusing [attr.disabled] for years thinking (or rather not much thinking) it´s equal to [disabled]...

Comment: This needs more context.

Answer (score 15):

```
<input [disabled]="is_edit" id="name" type="text">
<button (click)="is_edit = !is_edit">Change input state</button>

export class AppComponent {
  is_edit : boolean = false;
}
```

Comment: If you put console log in the isDisabled method, there are hundreds of console log are executed. If there is a complex logic in the isDisabled method, it might be a problem. So I am not sure this is a good solution.

Comment: Do not put dynamic checking into Angular variables or you get an infinite loop. You can use `[disabled]="is_edit"` directly. Why the `isDisabled()` function?

Answer (score 7):

I presume you meant `false` instead of `'false'`

Also, `[disabled]` is expecting a `Boolean`. You should avoid returning a `null`.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer this solution

In HTML file:

```
<input [disabled]="dynamicVariable" id="name" type="text">
```

In TS file:

```
dynamicVariable = false; // true based on your condition
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the currently recommended approach when using **reactive forms** (in order to avoid 'changed after checked' errors) is not to use the disabled attribute with a reactive form directive.
You should set up `disabled` property of this control in your component class and the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for you.

```html
<div>
      <form [formGroup]="form">
    <p>
        <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name"/>
    </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

and the component code:

```js
form: FormGroup;
  public is_edit: boolean = true;
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
    ) {
    
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: [{value: '', disabled: !this.is_edit}, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
    });
  }
```

Here is a plunker with the working code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/SQjxKBfvvUk2uAIb?preview

Answer (score 3):

A note in response to Belter's comment on [fedtuck's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43765804/8021088) above, since I lack the reputation to add comments.

This is not true for any of which I am aware, in line with the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled)

> disabled equals to true or false

When the disabled attribute is present the element is disabled regardless of value. See [this example](https://plnkr.co/edit/2f94nWkQCY4yOQsFhsMr?p=preview)

```
<input placeholder="i can be changed"/>
<input disabled placeholder="i can NOT be changed"/>
<input disabled="true" placeholder="i can NOT be changed"/>
<input disabled="false" placeholder="i can NOT be changed"/>
```

Comment: that is true and wholly true for pure Html, but for angular, you have to provide a boolean value for disabled especially when you are doing two way binding.

Answer (score 2):

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/sYFropu3cuJX5BcFLyE2?p=preview)

make `is_edit` of type boolean.

```
<input [disabled]=is_edit id="name" type="text">

export class App {
  name:string;
  is_edit: boolean; 
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
    this.is_edit = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is **disabled="true"**. Here is an example:

```
<textarea class="customPayload" disabled="true" *ngIf="!showSpinner"></textarea>
```

Comment: This is incorrect, the HTML and DOM `disabled` attribute is a "boolean attribute" which means only the attribute name needs to be specified - or its value must equal `disabled`, e.g. `disabled="disabled" - it does not recognize the values of `true` or `false` - so `disabled="false"` will still cause the element to be disabled.

Answer (score 2):

---

Disable TextBox in Angular 7

```
<div class="center-content tp-spce-hdr">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row mx-0 mt-4">
      <div class="col-12" style="padding-right: 700px;" >
          <div class="form-group">
              <label>Email</label>
                <input [disabled]="true" type="text" id="email" name="email" 
                [(ngModel)]="email" class="form-control">
          </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Disabled `Select` in angular 9.

one thing keep in mind disabled work with `boolean` values
in this example, I am using the `(change)` event with the `select` option if the country is not selected region will be disabled.

find.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-find',
  templateUrl: './find.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./find.component.css']
})
export class FindComponent implements OnInit {
  isCountrySelected:boolean;

  constructor() { }
  //onchange event disabled false
 onChangeCountry(id:number){
   this.isCountrySelected = false;
 }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    //initially disabled true
    this.isCountrySelected = true;
  }

}
```

find.component.html

```
//Country select option
<select  class="form-control"  (change)="onChangeCountry()" value="Choose Country">
                    <option value="">Choose a Country</option>
                    <option value="US">United States</option>
                     
</select>
//region disabled till country is not selected 
<select class="form-control" [disabled]="isCountrySelected">
                    <option value="">Choose a Region</option>
                    <option value="">Any regions.</option>
                    
                </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

And also if the input box/button has to remain disable, then simply
`<button disabled>` or `<input disabled>` works.

Answer (score -2):

can use simply like

```
     <input [(ngModel)]="model.name" disabled="disabled"
```

I got it like this way. so i prefer.

Comment: This is not setting the disabled attribute dynamically