# Angular [disabled]="MyBoolean" not working

Tags: angular, property-binding

I have some inputs (Checkboxes) and I want them to be disabled if my Booleans are true.
But its not working... The funny thing is the submit button works just fine and thats the same method...

myComponent.html

```c#
          <form [formGroup]="BetreuungsoptionForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <label *ngIf="!eingetragen" for="art">Art</label>
            <select *ngIf="!eingetragen" formControlName="art" id="art" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="Art" required >
              <option value="festeAnmeldung">feste Anmeldung</option>
              <option value="flexibleAnmeldung">flexible Anmeldung</option>
            </select>
            <label for="datum">Beginn Datum</label>
            <input formControlName="datum" type="date" id="datum" class="form-control" required>
            <label *ngIf="(Art == 'festeAnmeldung')" for="montag">Montag</label>
            <input *ngIf="(Art == 'festeAnmeldung')" formControlName="montag" [disabled]="montag" type="checkbox" id="montag" class="form-control wochentag">
            <label *ngIf="(Art == 'festeAnmeldung')" for="dienstag">Dienstag</label>
            <input *ngIf="(Art == 'festeAnmeldung')" formControlName="dienstag" [disabled]="dienstag" type="checkbox" id="dienstag" class="form-control wochentag">
            <label *ngIf="(Art == 'festeAnmeldung')" for="mittwoch">Mittwoch</label>
            <input *ngIf="(Art == 'festeAnmeldung')" formControlName="mittwoch" [disabled]="mittwoch" type="checkbox" id="mittwoch" class="form-control wochentag">
            <label *ngIf="(Art == 'festeAnmeldung')" for="donnerstag">Donnerstag</label>
            <input *ngIf="(Art == 'festeAnmeldung')" formControlName="donnerstag" [disabled]="donnerstag" type="checkbox" id="donnerstag" class="form-control wochentag">
            <label *ngIf="(Art == 'festeAnmeldung')" for="freitag">Freitag</label>
            <input *ngIf="(Art == 'festeAnmeldung' )" formControlName="freitag" [disabled]="freitag" type="checkbox" id="freitag" class="form-control wochentag">
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="!BetreuungsoptionForm.valid" class ="btn btn-primary">Speichern</button>
        <button type="button" (click)="OnBetreuungsoptionInfos()" class ="btn btn-success">weitere Informationen</button>
        <button type="button" *ngIf="!gekuendigt" (click)="OnBetreuungsoptionLoeschen()" class ="btn btn-danger">Kündigen</button>
      </form>
```

myComponent.ts

```ts
        this.BetreuungsoptionForm = new FormGroup
        ({
          art: new FormControl(),
          datum: new FormControl(this.BetreuungsoptionenKindRef[d].Beginn.toString().substring(0,10)),
          montag: new FormControl(this.BetreuungsoptionenKindRef[d].Montag),
          dienstag: new FormControl(this.BetreuungsoptionenKindRef[d].Dienstag),
          mittwoch: new FormControl(this.BetreuungsoptionenKindRef[d].Mittwoch),
          donnerstag: new FormControl(this.BetreuungsoptionenKindRef[d].Donnerstag),
          freitag: new FormControl(this.BetreuungsoptionenKindRef[d].Freitag)
        })
          if(this.BetreuungsoptionenKindRef.Montag)
          {
            this.montag = true;
          }
          if(this.BetreuungsoptionenKindRef.Dienstag)
          {
            this.dienstag = true;
          }
          if(this.BetreuungsoptionenKindRef.Mittwoch)
          {
            this.mittwoch = true;
          }
          if(this.BetreuungsoptionenKindRef.Donnerstag)
          {
            this.donnerstag = true;
          }
          if(this.BetreuungsoptionenKindRef.Freitag)
          {
            this.freitag = true;
          }
```

Comment: This one is related to same issue, and works well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179150/how-to-disable-a-input-in-angular2/43765804

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Try `[attr.disabled]="freitag? true : null"` or `[attr.readonly]="freitag"` instead.

You are able to use attributes like `[class.btn-lg]="someValue"` in a similar way.

Your textbox works because of this:

> The disabled attribute is another peculiar example. A button's
> disabled property is false by default so the button is enabled. When
> you add the disabled attribute, its presence alone initializes the
> button's disabled property to true so the button is disabled.
>
> Adding and removing the disabled attribute disables and enables the
> button. The value of the attribute is irrelevant, which is why you
> cannot enable a button by writing `<button disabled="false">Still Disabled</button>`.

from https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

Comment: I tried that already but its not working.. if i use attr.disabled everything is disabled and if I use disbaled everything is enabled

Comment: With inputs the presence of the disabled attribute disables the input regardless of the value

Comment: Ahh thank you it's working! And Thanks fpr the explanation

Comment: I found having this statement, "freitag? true : null", was important for it to start working. I believe what it does is checks the property "freitag". if it is true, it sets the value of disabled to true. If it is false, it sets it to null. From what I understand, null just removes the attribute altogether.

Comment: [attr.readonly]="true or false" it same result (readonly) but  [attr.readonly]="freitag? true : null"<<  it work! thank you

Answer (score 31):

Try this, trust me it's working..

```
<input [disabled]="isLoading ? true : null" />
```

Use `null` instead of `false`

Comment: Not working for me on Angular 9, setting to null still disables the input

Comment: <input [disabled]="condition ? true : false">
<input [attr.disabled]="condition ? 'disabled' : null">

Comment: I'm afraid it does not work on Angular 11

Comment: `Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | boolean'`

Comment: @CodeFinity just change null to false should fix the error
`<input [disabled]="isLoading ? true : false" />`

Comment: Tx. I don't even recall what this issue was about now. I believe I got it resolved by now.

Comment: This doesn't work in Angular 13. You'll get "Type 'true | null' is not assignable to type 'string | boolean'.  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | boolean'." You need to do `[attr.disabled]="isLoading ? true : null"`

Comment: for me Not working

Comment: use [attr.disabled] insted of [disabled]

Answer (score 21):

Reactive forms don't support native 'disabled' attribute. If you want them to work the way you wanted, try exploring this : https://netbasal.com/disabling-form-controls-when-working-with-reactive-forms-in-angular-549dd7b42110

Also see Angular reactive forms doc to do something like this in form control.

Eg: new FormControl({value:'tom', disabled: true})

Comment: They seem to work fine when I use them. For example [disabled]="some.form.status == 'INVALID'" works well.

Answer (score 4):

Reactive Forms:

.html file:

`<textarea class="form-control" rows="4" formControlName="message" [readonly]="disableMessage"></textarea>`

.ts file:

`disableMessage = true;`

Answer (score 3):

Sometime, I have to use 'ChangeDetectorRef' to refresh ui, then all disabled states work well.

*component.ts*

```
ready = false;
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){...}
private setReady(yes: boolean){
    this.ready = yes;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

*component.html*

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100" [disabled]="!ready" i18n>Continue</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap and apply any background colour using class, just remove it. it will work.

```html
        <button type="submit" class='**bg-primary** text-left form-control w-auto text-white mt-4' [disabled]="manageUsers.invalid">Submit</button>
```

Please remove "bg-primary" in class field. then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem in my Angular app, it seemed a silly problem for me cause I disabled/enabled a couple of my elements with [disabled] or [attr.disabled] though in part of my app these things didn't work, since I was time poor & wasn't able to investigate my codes deeply I used a trick which is not the best way but it works

```
 <input
      *ngIf="activationEmail != ''; else EmailInput"
      [attr.disabled]="true"
      [value]="activationEmail"
      class="form-control form-control-lg"
    />
    <ng-template #EmailInput>
      <input
        class="form-control form-control-lg"
        type="email"
        formControlName="email"
        autocomplete="off"
        [ngClass]="{
          'is-invalid':
            registrationForm.controls['email'].invalid &&
            registrationForm.controls['email'].touched
        }"
      />
    </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

For angular2 with reactiveform use like below example:

this.BetreuungsoptionForm.get('montag').disable();

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers, currently present, resolved my issue.

In my case, it was a symptom that Angular had *other* issues with my form. Upon enabling Chrome Developer Tools, I saw the following error output in the Developer Tools console:

> core.mjs:8416 ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.
> at getMatFormFieldMissingControlError (form-field.mjs:430:12)
> at MatFormField._assertFormFieldControl (form-field.mjs:705:19)
> at MatFormField.ngAfterContentChecked (form-field.mjs:613:14)
> at callHook (core.mjs:2460:18)
> at callHooks (core.mjs:2419:17)
> at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:2370:9)
> at refreshView (core.mjs:10383:21)
> at refreshComponent (core.mjs:11401:13)
> at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:10132:9)
> at refreshView (core.mjs:10392:13)

It turned out that I was missing the matInput attribute in my `<input>` fields. E.g. change `<input id="category"...` to `<input matInput id="category"...`

Once I resolved the error message, that was only visible via the Developer Tools Console, the `[disabled]` directive started to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

USE readonly and css class `<input type="text" [disabled]="true" readonly class="form-control link-input" [(ngModel)]="permaLink" formControlName="permalink" >` `.cursor{ cursor: not-allowed !important; }`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

in my case, I was wrongly using FormControl, expecting that it's having the control name like  `[formControl]="CtrlName"` when I removed it, disabled working fine now.

Here is the disabled tag that worked for me

```
[disabled]="isDisabledVariable"
```

Answer (score -1):

Note: **If you are using an Angular Material** button, a good example is:

```
<button mat-button [disabled]="condition">Button</button>
```

This works since the library defines an input property for passing in a "disabled" value, i.e. `@Input('disabled')`.

Answer (score -3):

For me none of the above worked, including the below

```
[disabled]="!enableDelete">
```

What worked for me was

```
[disabled]="enableSave == 'false'">
```

Comment: Sounds like your `enableSave` was a string `'false'` rather than a boolean `false`.

Comment: than probably [disabled]="!!enableSave"> would work to force it into a boolean