# Submit button disable based on checkbox and form validation not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an angular form, I use angular material stepper, I want the submit button to by disabled when the form is invalid and be automatically enabled on edit page if the form is valid

I tried to put both it did not work, the checkbox works it enables and disables

```
 <mat-step>
  <form [formGroup]="thirdFormGroup" #programAvailability="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="form3()">
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Confirm & submit</ng-template>
    <mat-checkbox formControlName="agreementCtrl" (change)="changeCheck($event)"> I agree to....</mat-checkbox>
    <div>
      <button mat-raised-button  matStepperPrevious>Back</button> &nbsp;
      <button mat-raised-button [disabled]="disabledAgreement && thirdFormGroup.invalid" color="primary" matStepperNext type="submit" >Submit</button>
      &nbsp;
      <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</mat-step>
```

and my component:

```
 changeCheck(event) {
    this.disabledAgreement = !event.checked;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

1. You need to use [attr.disabled] instead of [disabled]
2. The value that you bind to [attr.disabled] needs to be a string, and the values are 'disabled' and null. This is not a boolean.

Comment: I put it as you said           <button mat-raised-button [attr.disabled]="disabledAgreement && thirdFormGroup.invalid" color="primary" matStepperNext type="submit" >Submit</button>

Comment: but it disabled the button and can not be changed based on agreement checkbox

Comment: Hmm...Point 1 - why is this (angular or material) / do you have any relevant documentation link? Not had an issue in my own code using disabled directly

Comment: You are still binding a boolean. It needs to be 
null to enable the button. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50130924/angular-disabled-myboolean-not-working

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the submit button to be disabled if the agreement checked box is not checked or if the form is disabled. If so, you need to use the || (Logical OR) operator instead of && (Logical AND), like so:

```
<button mat-raised-button [disabled]="disabledAgreement || thirdFormGroup.invalid" color="primary" matStepperNext type="submit" >Submit</button>
```

Comment: I added did or operator but on update page it does keeps the button disabled