# How to disable textarea based on the value selected from dropdown

Tags: angular

I want to disable text-area based on the option selected from the dropdown values. In my `component.ts` file, I have defined a variable to keep a track of if the text area is to be disabled or not

`messageDisabled: boolean = false`, and there is a function that triggers on change of dropdown value

```
getdropdownGender(event) {
    const value = event;
    if (value == 'a' || value == 'b')
      this.messageDisabled = true
    else
      this.messageDisabled = false
  }
```

The part of my `component.html` file is

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Gender</label><span class="asterick">*</span>
                <select
                  type="text"
                  formControlName="gender"
                  class="form-control border-primary"
                  [(ngModel)]="selected_gender"
                  #t
                  (change)="getdropdownGender(t.value)"
                >
                  <option value="">Select Gender</option>
                  <option
                    value="{{ _position }}"
                    *ngFor="let _position of genderList"
                  >
                    {{ _position }}
                  </option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Message</label>
                <textarea
                  [disabled]="messageDisabled"
                  cols="30"
                  rows="3"
                  type="text"
                  class="form-control border-primary"
                  formControlName="message"
                  placeholder="Message"
                >
                </textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

But the `[disabled]` parameter in the text area is not working (based on the condition of `messageDisabled` value). Can anyone please help me resolve this issue ?

Comment: Have you checked if the `messageDisabled` changes its value as you expect? I can't see the issue in the code that you posted. `[disabled]` looks fine

Comment: @Adrian Kokot yes, `messageDisabled` value is changing as expected when the dropdown value changes. But the text area `disabled` functionality is not changing. Based on the code written above, the text area is not getting disabled in any of the drop-down values

Comment: @AdrianKokot if I use `attr.disabled` in place of `disabled`, then the text area always remains `disabled`

Comment: Have you tried setting to `null` if false? Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50130924/angular-disabled-myboolean-not-working)?

Comment: Yes, @AdrianKokot its working when setting to null if false. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use *ngif

```
<textarea *ngIf="value == 'a' || value == 'b'" cols="30" rows="3" type="text"
            class="form-control border-primary" formControlName="message" placeholder="Message">
      </textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

The disabled attribute is a boolean attribute. Since it's not required a value you can do like this:

```
<textarea {{ messageDisabled ? "disabled" : "" }}></textarea>
```

or

```
<textarea {{ messageDisabled ? "disabled='disabled'" : "" }}></textarea>
```