# Display input box on condition in angular reactive form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5, angular6

I am making angular 6 application where i am using angular reactive form.

**Html:**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">

    <h2>Click the add button below</h2>
    <button (click)="addCreds()">Add</button>
        <div formArrayName="credentials" *ngFor="let creds of form.controls.credentials?.value; let i = index">
          <div [formGroupName]="i" style="display: flex">
            <select (ngModelChange)="changeAction($event)" formControlName="action">
              <option *ngFor="let option of options" value="{{option.key}}"> {{option.value}} </option>
            </select>
            <input placeholder="Name" formControlName="name">
            <div *ngIf="showLabel">
            <input placeholder="Label" formControlName="label">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </form>

    <pre>
      {{ form ?.value | json }}
    </pre>
```

**Ts:**

```
  form: FormGroup;
  showLabel: boolean = false;

  options : any = [ 
    { "key" : "set", "value": "Set" },
    { "key" : "wait", "value": "Wait" },
    { "key" : "go", "value": "Go" }   
    ]

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      credentials: this.fb.array([]),
    });
  }

  addCreds() {
    const creds = this.form.controls.credentials as FormArray;
    creds.push(this.fb.group({
      action: '',
      name: '',
      label: ''
    }));
  }

  changeAction(e) {
    if(e === "set" || e === "go") {
      this.showLabel = true;
    } else {
      this.showLabel = false;
    }
  }
```

**Working stackblitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example-yksojj

In this given example there will be an add button, upon clicking that button you will get a `select-box` with values as `set,wait,go` and an input called name.. Upon click over add button the same row will be added and forms each object inside array.

Also you can see an `if` condition inside html for label,

```
<div *ngIf="showLabel">
  <input placeholder="Label" formControlName="label">
</div>
```

The thing **i am in the need** was in the select box if i choose **set or go** then the label needs to displayed otherwise it should not be displayed for which i have written,

```
  changeAction(e) {
    if(e === "set" || e === "go") {
      this.showLabel = true;
    } else {
      this.showLabel = false;
    }
  }
```

**To be clear enough** If the user clicks three times add button then the dropdown and name field alone needs to be displayed for three times whereas if the user selects the value from dropdown as **set or go** then the label input needs to be displayed to that **particular row alone where the dropdown has the value set and go**.. If the selection was `wait` then there should not be label box for the row which has dropdown value as `wait`.

Kindly help me to achieve the expected result..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add disabled:true property to formControl it will exclude fromControl from formGroup then you can enable formControl manually

```
creds.push(this.fb.group({
      action: '',
      name: '',
      label: {disabled:true, value: ""}
    }));
```

Then enable using enable method

```
changeAction(e,index) {
    if(e === "set" || e === "go") {
      this.showLabel = true;     
     this.form.get('credentials').at(index).get('label').enable();

    } else {
      this.showLabel = false;
      this.form.get('credentials').at(index).get('label').disable();
    }
  }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example-5buwyr

Comment: Bro three state switch needs to be inside the reactive form and inside formarray for which i have used the following https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example-iwecg7 but unable to see even the toggle buttons..

Answer (score 2):

Please, NOT use `(ngModelChange)` or `changeAction($event)` to get the value of a control in an array -well, `ngModelChange` is for Template driven form, **not** for Reactive Form.

First change your form, create the form using a div with `formArrayName="credentials"`, and a inner `div *ngFor="let creds of form.get('credentials')`.**controls**

```
    <!--a div with formArrayName--->
    <div formArrayName="credentials" >
      <!--a div *ngFor over "controls", in this div don't forget formGroupName-->
      <div *ngFor="let creds of form.get('credentials').controls; let i = index" 
          [formGroupName]="i" style="display: flex">
          <select formControlName="action">
             <option *ngFor="let option of options" value="{{option.key}}">
               {{option.value}} 
             </option>
          </select>
          <input placeholder="Name" formControlName="name">
          <div *ngIf="??????????????">
             <input placeholder="Label" formControlName="label">
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Well, now the condition. To get the value of "action" you can use

```
form.get('credentials').at(i).value.action
//or, better
creds.value.action
```

So, your div becomes like

```
<div *ngIf="creds.value.action=='set' ||
      creds.value.action=='go'">
  <input placeholder="Label" formControlName="label">
</div>
```

This aproach avoid unnecesary code in your .ts.

Comment: Thanks Eliseo, can i hsve stackblitz along with your solution??

Comment: is your forked stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example-7kmhuv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: If i am able to disable the input then its not working, tried ```[disabled]="creds.value.action != 'set' ||
      creds.value.action != 'go' "``` and the stackblitz of the same was https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example-2q1r4p

Comment: If i am not willing to remove the label input box but it can be disabled instead..So how can i achieve it without going for ts??

Comment: Use a directive to enabled/disable the control https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47937639/how-to-make-a-disabled-reactive-form-editable-in-angular2 and replace *ngIf="condition" by [enableControl]="condition"

Comment: Thanks Eliseo please give me some working example so that it might be helpful for me..

Comment: Eliseo, I have posted new question regarding it please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53948456/disable-a-field-in-angular-reactive-form

Comment: @Undefined, just create a directive and use it.

Comment: I have not used directive yet in any angular application Eliseo.. Always you give me more than what i am in need but here i am unable to make disable please help me..

Comment: I updated the stackblitz. A directive it's easy. It's only a .ts that you must include in "declarations" of the module. See that, this directive has in constructor "NgControl". That's important, because you only can use this directive in a "FormControl" (or in a input). Perhafs I confussed you when say that you need replace *ngIf=condition -the *ngIf was in a "div", not in a control

Answer (score 1):

```
this.showLabel
```

The scope of this variable is your whole component. Therefore, turning it on or off will show and hide all inputs.

You need a per-row value (`creds.showLabel` in your interface), or use this in your template :

```
*ngIf="['set','go'].includes(creds.action)"
```

[Updated Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example-3ctjfe)

By the way, this :

```
changeAction(e) {
    if(e === "set" || e === "go") {
      this.showLabel = true;
    } else {
      this.showLabel = false;
    }
  }
```

is more elegant written this way :

```
changeAction(e) {
    this.showLabel = ['set','go'].includes(e)
}
```

or this way :

```
changeAction(e) {
    this.showLabel = e in ['set','go']
}
```

Comment: Very nicely explained, but link is broken. Please add.

Comment: What is the solution if in do not want to remove but only disable the input box?? I have tried ```[disabled]="creds.value.action != 'set' || creds.value.action != 'go' "``` but it doesn't works..

Comment: Use `[attr.disabled]` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179150/how-to-disable-a-input-in-angular2/43765804

Answer (score 1):

Well, [Jeremy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1021703/jeremy-thille) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53934231/6446770) is pretty nice and enforces to use most of the native apis given by platform/language, however, here is a **traditional** approach to understand what is the actual flow and scope of objects, etc,etc...

**Root Cause:** The show hide field is made global to the scope of component, not at per `formgroup` level. So changing a single value, and using for all, will affect to all.

**Solution:**

1. Use [Jeremy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1021703/jeremy-thille) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53934231/6446770) for clean coding and less error prone code.
2. Manage an array of variable that will take care of sho/hide detail for each form group.

In the below answer, added some comments for easy understanding, and added console.log to see what exactly happening. Also, played with index `i` created in `*ngFor` and showed how you can make use of these things in future.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormArray, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent  {
  form: FormGroup ;
  showLabel = [];
  creds : FormArray; 
  options : any = [ 
    { "key" : "set", "value": "Set" },
    { "key" : "wait", "value": "Wait" },
    { "key" : "go", "value": "Go" }   
    ]

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      credentials: this.fb.array([]),
    });
    this.creds = this.form.controls.credentials as FormArray;
  }

  addCreds() {
    
    this.creds.push(this.fb.group({
      action: '',
      name: '',
      label: ''
    }));
    // every time adding new foem grp, adding lable show/hide data also.
  this.showLabel.push(false);

  }

  changeAction(e, i) {
    //every time input clikced, managing show/hide for that particular data also
    console.log("iii", i, e.target.value);
    if( e.target.value == "set" ||  e.target.value == "go") {
      this.showLabel[i] = true;
    } else {
      this.showLabel[i] = false;
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">

 <h2>Click the add button below</h2>
 <button (click)="addCreds()">Add</button>
        <div formArrayName="credentials" *ngFor="let creds of form.controls.credentials?.value; let i = index">
          <div [formGroupName]="i" >
            <select (change)="changeAction($event, i)" formControlName="action">
              <option *ngFor="let option of options" value="{{option.key}}"> {{option.value}} </option>
            </select>
            <input placeholder="Name" formControlName="name">
            <div *ngIf="showLabel[i]">
            <input placeholder="Label" formControlName="label">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </form>

    <pre>
      {{ form ?.value | json }}
    </pre>
```

[**See live stackblitz working code**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example-jae4uz)

Note: **Traditional** is meant here.. *as we every time do i.e. handle our problem on our own and create new problem on us to solve.* It's not a tradition. :P