# Angular 6 input file prevent file dialog opening

Tags: angular, file, input

I've a simple input of type file and I need to check a boolean variable before opening the file dialog to choose a file. Is there a way to do this?
This is my code:

```
<input type="file" id="uploadFile" [disabled]="disableUpload" (change)="onUpload($event)" />
```

Clicking on input, a file dialog is shown. I need to do a check that, if positive, block the file dialog opening.
Thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try adding `attr.disabled` instead of `disabled`

```
<input [attr.disabled]="disableUpload ? '' : null"/>
```

Or if you are using [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) (I suggest you to do so), you may disable it using the form control.

**UPDATE**

You can assign a method to `click` event on file input and then check for the boolean value to perform desired operation.

In the component:

```
fileDialogShouldOpen = false;

fileInputClick = (event) => {

    // Open file dialog
    if(this.fileDialogShouldOpen){
      return true;
    }
    // Do not open file dialog
    else{

      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      return false;
    }
}
```

And in the template:

```
<input type="file" (click)="fileInputClick($event)">
```

You can find a working example in this [stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dsbv9k)

Comment: And also see: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179150/how-to-disable-a-input-in-angular2/43765804](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179150/how-to-disable-a-input-in-angular2/43765804)

Comment: I don't want to disable the input, I just want to do something (checking a boolean) before opening the file dialog to choose a file. If check result false I don't want to open the file dialog.

Comment: @bigskull Glad to help :)

Comment: @bigskull Btw, instead of editing the title as "solved", you may mark the working answer as accepted. Please see: [https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question)

Comment: The update works perfectly. Thx!