# Why does this line in Angular Material source code has `|| null`?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to create my own component library for another CSS framework. So I studied the source code of Angular Material as an example. And then I came across this line:

https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/2a086ce4751d71db8cfb85a33e2ca702f02ce1c0/src/lib/button/button.ts#L73

```js
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: `button[mat-button], button[mat-raised-button], button[mat-icon-button],
             button[mat-fab], button[mat-mini-fab], button[mat-stroked-button],
             button[mat-flat-button]`,
  exportAs: 'matButton',
  host: {
    '[disabled]': 'disabled || null', // This line!
    '[class._mat-animation-noopable]': '_animationMode === "NoopAnimations"',
  },
  templateUrl: 'button.html',
  styleUrls: ['button.css'],
  inputs: ['disabled', 'disableRipple', 'color'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class MatButton extends _MatButtonMixinBase {
  ...
}
```

I just want to confirm my understanding, is the line I highlighted does not need to have `|| null` part?

My understanding is as follows: this component is bind to a `HTMLButtonElement`, which has its own `disabled` property. The boolean value can be passed to the element just fine.

Any answer would be appreciated. (Especially Kara, as it was you who introduced this line :P)

Comment: I believe it's used in order to NOT set the disabled on the element. something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179150/how-to-disable-a-input-in-angular2).

Comment: sorry misunderstood previously

Comment: Setting `[disabled]="false"` or `[disabled]="null"` on a button appears to give the same result. That code may have been copied/pasted from [another part of the code](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/2a086ce4751d71db8cfb85a33e2ca702f02ce1c0/src/lib/button/button.ts#L73) where they bind `[attr.disabled]`. In the case of the attribute, it makes a difference. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7trq1j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: @Stavm That's my point. Because it is binding to `HTMLButtonElement`'s `disabled` property, which can be set to false or true. So I think that line doesn't need the `|| null` part?

Comment: @ConnorsFan, that's one of my theory too that the line was copied from the class below.

Comment: @ConnorsFan and I think you mean [this line](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/2a086ce4751d71db8cfb85a33e2ca702f02ce1c0/src/lib/button/button.ts#L156) instead?

Comment: @SarunIntaralawan - Yes. That is what we get when we copy/paste and don't check afterwards, like I did when writing my previous comment. :-)

Comment: @ConnorsFan could you please "convert" that comment of yours into an answer below? So I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding the `disabled` button **property** to the values `false` or `null` both keep the button enabled:

```
<button [disabled]="false"> --> Button enabled
<button [disabled]="null">  --> Button enabled
```

Consequently, I don't see why they use `disabled || null`. I suspect the [line of code](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/2a086ce4751d71db8cfb85a33e2ca702f02ce1c0/src/lib/button/button.ts#L73) referred to in the question to have been copied/pasted from [another part of the code](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/2a086ce4751d71db8cfb85a33e2ca702f02ce1c0/src/lib/button/button.ts#L156), where the `disabled` **attribute** is bound. In the case of the attribute, binding to `false` disables the button (it sets the attribute to the string `"false"`, which is truthy), while binding to `null` keeps the button enabled (it removes the `disabled` attribute):

```
<button [attr.disabled]="false"> --> Button disabled
<button [attr.disabled]="null">  --> Button enabled
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7trq1j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.