# Is it safe to disable the submit button if formGroup is invalid in Angular

Tags: angular, submit, angular-reactive-forms

I'm working on a project where I have to deal with lots of forms in Angular. When I disable the submit button, I get this warning message on  the console:

```
 It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form directive. If you set disabled to true
      when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for
      you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors.

      Example: 
      form = new FormGroup({
        first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
        last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
      });
```

Comment: Could you show your part of the code which led to the error? It looks like you use the `disabled` property directly in HTML while setting it in TS is recommended.

Comment: @QuanVO that is precisely what I am doing disabling it in the HTML template... Is that wrong?

Comment: please show your HTML

Comment: Yes, I think the error is detailed enough. Please show your code so we could help more easily.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable a input in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179150/how-to-disable-a-input-in-angular2)