# Disable button and input-field through angular Directive

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular12

I am trying to disable button and input-field through angular directive based on the permission. I have tried few ways but it doesn't help

```
if (this.permission==true) {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        } else {
          const viewRootElement : HTMLElement = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(
            this.templateRef
          ).rootNodes[0];
          viewRootElement.setAttribute('disabled', 'false');

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. For the Reactive Forms usage you may use directive for that

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[disableControl]'
})
export class DisableControlDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input() disableControl = false;

  constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) {}
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes['disableControl'] && this.ngControl.control) {
      const action = this.disableControl ? 'disable' : 'enable';
      this.ngControl.control[action]();
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can use it on input or button

```html
<input [formControl]="formControl" [disableControl]="disable">
<button (click)="disable = true">Disable</button>
<button (click)="disable = false">Enable</button>
```

2. For the usual input you should just use [readonly] - it will be both reactive and working (see explanation why `disabled` is bad [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179150/how-to-disable-a-input-in-angular2))

Comment: am getting Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531) in this.control

Comment: I've updated the answer a little bit, it should be fixed now

Comment: and am not using forms either! its not working

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were talking about forms input. for the usual one please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179150/how-to-disable-a-input-in-angular2

Answer (score 0):

For the button disabled you can use this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="disablebtn" (click)="submit()">Upload</button>
```

In .ts file:

```
disablebtn:boolean=false;
submit(){
this.disablebtn=true;
}
```

For the input field you can use this:

```
<input type="text" [disabled]="true">
```

Comment: I was asking through the angular directive

Answer (score 0):

First: you want to create a directive, which targets button and input.

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'input[dis], button[dis]',
})
```

Next: you need to know how to toggle the `disable` state of a button/input

```
this.render.setProperty(
            this.el.nativeElement,
            'disabled',
            true //false
          );
```

Last: in that directive, use your `permission service` to toggle the element state, in this case is disable state.

```
this.perService.permission$
      .pipe(
        tap((hasPermission) => {
          //get permission value and set the disable state
          );
        })
      )
```

You can find the full working code in the below link.
[Working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zhkhwh)